# Conversion from NTLM to Kerberos authentication in SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, kerberos, ntlm

We initially setup NTLM authentication, in the interest of time. We realized that Chrome doesn't work with NTLM. How can I seamlessly convert to Kerberos without breaking anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "Chrome does not work", I use chrome all the time to access SP2019 with NTLM.

Comment: Also not sure about what do you mean by Chrome doesn‘t work with NTLM... If you wanna convert web application authentication from NTLM to Kerberoes, you can edit their Authentication Providers and set Kerberoes firstly, configure NTLM authentication for web apps then. Guide: https://vivekmalviya.home.blog/2019/03/21/part2-step-by-step-guide-for-configuring-kerberos-authentication-for-sharepoint-webapplication/

Comment: Whenever we use Chrome to pull up our intranet Sharepoint site, we get the 401 unauthorized error. This only happens in Chrome